What are the 11 different aspects of Shiva in form of Rudhra(Destroyer)?
Shiva is often termed as a god of destruction. But Rudhra, one of the aspect of Shiva is considered as destructor, not the Shiva himself. Moreover, arguments are there about Shiva as a destroyer of problems and not the life forms. If Rudhra is said to be a form of Shiva who has 11 different aspects. How many actual avatars does Shiva has?

Is Śiva a Destroyer?
Śiva is often translated as the destroyer, this is a linguistic error during translation. Destruction and dissolution are separate concepts, where destruction means to damage the composition of an object, resulting in remnants. For example, if we destroy an apple, the apple loses its shape but the parts or pieces of the apple are thrown apart or burnt to ash; hence destruction always has a byproduct or a leftover. Dissolution means, the product merges into something else and loses its independent existence. This is very similar to the conservation of Quantum Information. Say an apple is destroyed beyond visible recognition; whatever information that consists of, the quantum properties that make up the apple are never destroyed. Hence, the word “destroyer” creates a vague interpretation as if Śiva attacks people or things and distorts them. In fact, Śiva as Rudra is Pralaya Karaka, what does that mean? In the case of Pralaya (the closest word is dissolution), the object merges into the source as one (the concept of laya) and distribution is a part of the process and not the whole. This is done in 3 ways: Swalpakalika Laya, Aatyantica Laya, pra:laya / mahapra:laya. At the highest level, the throbbing within the Singularity just subsides. (Swami Venkatesananda. 1993 book Vasista Yogam, TED-Ed Quantum Information. 2019)
Swalpakalika (Swalpa:kalika)  a phenomenon of our conscience momentarily detaches itself from the body, the reality, and the outside physical world to slide into a resting state.
Aatyantica (Aatyan:tica) this ignite gyana (jnana) so that the atman recognizes the paramatma or itself to be the Parabrahma
Finally, pralaya(m) is a temporary reset of Bhumi (Earth) either through a calamity or by the beginning of a new era. Pralaya has an extended version known as mahapralaya (Mahā:pralayam), which is the complete dissolution of creation and all its realities to unify with its source, which is Parabrahma unified with śakti becoming a singularity. Hence, Parameshwari  (Pārameśvari) (the śakti also Devi Pārvatī) is the only one to witness this dissolution, hence known by the title ‘Mahā Parlaya Shakshini’. Paramatma (the supreme singular conscience) using its śakti stores the information required to restart a new creation. His śakti eventually oozes out of Him to form both the physical matter and also pure energy with which He (Iśvara) as Brahmā structures and builds a reality, as Śrī Vishnu (Viṣṇu) He strives towards its preservation.
Rudhra, one of the aspect of Shiva is considered as destructor ?
Today, the terms Apple and Windows took a different notation compared to a fruit and physical object. Similarly, Rudra of Vedas has Shiva as its adjective. But later Shiva the benevolent side took the highest stance and Rudra took the fierce side. Technically it's Ugra the correct adjective for the fierce side.
a destroyer of problems and not the life forms

“He who makes others cry during their dissolution, hence he is called
Rudra” “He who destroyed suffering and it’s cause, is Rudra” “He who
dispells our crying/sorrows is Rudra”
~ Adi Śankaracharya Vishu Sahasranama Bashya.

The same can be found in Brihadaranyaka Upanishad Bhyasa.
If Rudhra is said to be a form of Shiva who has 11 different aspects?
Shiva does not take Avataras, even though the Puranic literature says so. However, its up to the explorers to decide what constitutes an Avatar. In the Vedas, When the Vedic metre is considered, Rudras are associated with Triṣṭubh Metre which has 11 syllables multiplied by 4 steps, hence Śrī Rudram of the Kṛṣṇa Yajur Veda describes 11 homages to Rudra. The famous opening hymn lists 11 titles, they are: viśveśva̱rayā, mahādevāya, tryaṁbakāya, tripurāntakāya, trikalāgni-kālāya, kālāgnirudrāya, nīlakaṇṭhāya, mrutyuṁjayāya, sarveśvarāya, sadāśivāya, śrīman-mahādevāya .
Source Link1 Link2 Link3
